# Default Path for WebLogic site root on RedHat 5

Tags: web, redhat, weblogic11g, rhel5

I am flying blind and could use some help. I am a long time windows web developer/web admin and I have inherited a WebLogic 11g/RHEL5 box. I'm trying to figure out where the website files might be.

My only contact with the box is through FTP, and I'm not sure the account I'm using has all of the permissions I need.

Googling led me to check /opt/bea, but there is no/bea folder under /opt. Another possibility was /var/local/WebLogic, but there was no /WebLogic folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It just occurred to me that this request might sound suspicious, so here is a little more detail. I need to make some site edits by 10/10/2011. I submitted this request on 10/7 because our linux admins have all gone home for the weekend. If I can figure out how to find the website via FTP, I can make the edits this weekend. Otherwise, I'll be under a lot of pressure to work with the admins on Monday AND make the edits immediately after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to the server and execute "ps -ef | grep java"

In the output you should see a parameter named "-Dwls.home". That would point to the wls root.

Comment: That will be helpful when I can log into the server. Unfortunately, that is not an option right now.

Comment: Wow, that is really interesting. You could try "/usr", "/appl" or list the root directory and see if anything looks familiar. I am assuming have you tried logging in using the same credentials that you use for ftp and that has not worked either. If you dont have the option of having a unix admin execute the ps command you could try using the "quote" command within ftp. I believe the "quote" option allows you to execute remote commands. But I have not used ftp in ages so you will have to experiment a little.

Comment: Welp - I ended up working with the admins to solve this... but since there were no other suggestions - green check for you.